# Не работает jquery

Tags: jquery

такая схема:
подключение jquery

```
<script ...></script> 

<div id='div1'>
 контент
</div>
<form ..... action='/vit_write.php'>
 форма ввода текста
</form>
<div id='div2'>
 результат
</div>
```

После ввода текста в форму по submit данные попадают в vit_write.php там они обрабатываются и отправляются в блок div id='div2',т.е
vit_write.php:

```
<?php
.
.
обработка данных
.
.
?>
<script>
$("#div2").text(<?php echo $text; ?>);
</script>
```

вот это не работает, а работает так:

```
<script>
 window.parent.document.getElementById("div2").innerHTML=<?php echo $text; ?>;
</script>
```

Получается, что всё что связано с JQuery игнорируется, хотя вызов скриптов из блока div id=div1, где используется JQuery, работает. В какую сторону копать?

Comment: ну так покажите как вы подключаете jquery. возможно вы неправильно путь к библиотеке указали

Comment: что в консоли?

Comment: @metrander, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Answer (score 1):

1. `$("#div2").text(<?php echo $text; ?>);` - что возвращает $text? может просто пустоту, или крашиться на выражении без кавычек?, p.s. в новых версих php можно вот так писать: `$("#div2").text(<?=$text;?>);`
2. Возможно у вас конфликт с другими плагинами, пробуйте jQuery.noConflict(), а вместо $ используйте jQuery
3. Да и вообще, посмотрите что возвращает этот скрипт, почему он не выполняется `$("#div2").text(<?php echo $text; ?>);` - в хроме щелкните на F12 (Инструменты разработчика - ctrl+shift+i, или сразу консоль js - ctrl+shift+j)